# How to check the sum of 2 different string columns in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, string

I have a table with details of Customer like this

```
ID      F_NAME      L_NAME
1       Danny       Drinkwater
2       Danny       Ings
3       Wayne       Rooney
```

I want to return the names of those customers whose combined length of F_NAME and L_NAME is less than 12

I tried this query `Select F_NAME from Customer where(SUM(length(F_NAME))+length(L_NAME))))<12;`

But I am getting an error like this `Invalid use of group function`

Comment: Remove SUM and just add lengths.

Comment: Sum is for aggregating rows. You don't want to aggregate. Just do `WHERE length(F_NAME) + length(L_NAME) < 12`

Answer (score 1):

Just:

```
select f_name
mytable
where char_length(f_name) + char_length(l_name) < 12
```

Note that `char_length()` gives you the length of the string in characters, rather than in bytes (as given by `length()`).

Answer (score 1):

Your use of aggregate function SUM is wrong.

`SUM` you can use when you want to summarize result of different rows

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Customer
WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(f_name) + CHAR_LENGTH(l_name) < 12
```

In your case, if you use only simple letter and no special character you can use `LENGTH` instead of `CHAR_LENGTH`.  But `CHAR_LENGTH` it's OK for further use.